# What is the difference between Multipart and MIME content type?

Tags: http, protocols, mime, multipart, http-method

I have been going through the entity content type in HTTP verbs but actually I can't understand the differences of both and how they were related. Can someone explain me how both works in a transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mime-type is an identifier that describes the format of a HTTP body, a file, an email.

They all follow a "major-category/specific format" structure. All images for example start with `image/`.

`multipart/` is also a specific class of content-types that describes a format that is really multiple 'parts' each with their own format, wrapped into one larger format.

`multipart/form-data` for example is what's used when submitting a HTML form with a file, `multipart/alternative` is used in emails to encode *both* a text and HTML version for an email message. `multipart/mixed` is used to add attachments to email.

Comment: Is this works like this : A multipart is a collection of different formats with each format have its own MIME type.

Comment: @Venkat yeah you could wrap multiple `image/png` is 1 http request with multipart. Each part can have their own headers.